# How do I get time for a calculated column

Tags: sharepoint

In SharePoint [Today] returns 12:00 PM. 
How do I get current time?

Trying this as value for column "=Today+TIME(Hour(Today);Minute(Today)-10;0)".

This is for new items and it's to set default value for a DateTime column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware you can't use times with Today in a calculated column. Also if you aren't already aware, [Today does not update automatically](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/), only when you edit the list item.

JavaScript is the most common solution to this, although it's a little difficult to know what the options are without the full details. If you re-edit your question with exactly what you would like to do we can help further.

Comment: I've solved it with javascript. But thought that there should be a more SharePoint properly way.

This is for new items and it's to set default value for a DateTime column.

Comment: Accepts this as the answer, as it appears to be the only solution.